# htmlagilitypack usage cpu more than 50% in the multi-threads

Tags: c#, performance, html-agility-pack

my application use 10 threads that to read a lot of html file.similar the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    new Thread(ParserHtmlWork)
    {
       IsBackground = true
    }.Start();
}

void ParserHtmlWork()
{            
      while (true)
      {
          //read the next file from the queue.
          var filePath = Query.Enqueue();
          using (var stream = OpenFile(filePath))
          {
              stream.Close();
          }
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
      }
}
```

the above code running no problem,the avg cpu is 2%-5%,next i change my code that add the htmlagilitypack library that to parser html.

```
private HtmlDocument CreateHtmlDocument(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
{
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    ////Defines if the 'id' attribute must be specifically used. 
    doc.OptionUseIdAttribute = false;
    //Defines if declared encoding must be read from the document. 
    //Declared encoding is determined using the meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=XXXXX" html node
    doc.OptionReadEncoding = false;
    doc.Load(stream, encoding);
    return doc;
}
```

change the ParserHtmlWork method add invoke a CreateHtmlDocument method:

```
 using (var stream = OpenFile(filePath))
 {
     CreateHtmlDocument(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
     stream.Close();
 }
```

**running the above again,the avg cpu up to 50-60%**(the average file size is 80k).**if i decrease the thread number to 1,the ave cpu down to the 2%-5%.**

i capture the cpu sampling by the visual studio performance in my products(not the above code):

```
ApplicationEngine.Start()
Inclusive Samples: 398
Exclusive Samples: 0
Inclusive Samples %: 76
Exclusive Samples %: 0

ApplicationEngine.DoWork(class System.IO.Stream)
Inclusive Samples: 337
Exclusive Samples: 0
Inclusive Samples %: 64.44
Exclusive Samples %: 0.00

CreateHtmlDocument(class System.IO.Stream,class System.Text.Encoding)
Inclusive Samples: 298  
Exclusive Samples: 0
Inclusive Samples %: 56.98
Exclusive Samples %: 0.00

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load(class System.IO.Stream,class System.Text.Encoding)
Inclusive Samples: 296
Exclusive Samples: 0
Inclusive Samples %: 56.60
Exclusive Samples %: 0.00

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load(class System.IO.TextReader)
Inclusive Samples: 294
Exclusive Samples: 0
Inclusive Samples %: 56.21
Exclusive Samples %: 0.00

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Parse()
Inclusive Samples: 273
Exclusive Samples: 13
Inclusive Samples %: 52.20
Exclusive Samples %: 2.49

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.PushNodeEnd(int32,bool)
Inclusive Samples: 135
Exclusive Samples: 2
Inclusive Samples %: 25.81
Exclusive Samples %: 0.38

[clr.dll]   130 106 24.86   20.27

System.String.ToLower()             
Inclusive Samples: 118
Exclusive Samples: 118
Inclusive Samples %: 22.56
Exclusive Samples %: 22.56

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.get_Name()             
Inclusive Samples: 81
Exclusive Samples: 3
Inclusive Samples %: 15.49
Exclusive Samples %: 0.57
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what is your problem?

A HTML parser using CPU? What did you expect - the downloads do not, HTML parsing uses CPU, and if you use a lot of parallel threads then yes, this will add up.

Not a lot you can do - optimize HtmlAgilityPack via a proviler to see whether or not there is a bottleneck there. If not... well... get a faster processor / more servers or optimize your code.

Vote to close and -1 - I fail to see any related question here except "oh my god, my CPU is used when it has to do work".

Comment: i think HtmlAgilityPack  have a bottleneck in the multi-threads.i will try find to solved or other solution.

Comment: Possible, but then basically it is expected to use 10% cpu when 10 threads work AND - a profiler run would show possible bottlenecks easi.y investigate and post on their forums ;)

Comment: @TomTom if HtmlAgilityPack do has bottleneck what can be done to make a parser multithreaded?